# Inserting a dynamic variable value in a string in C

Tags: c, string, insert

I am facing this problem..

Lets say I have a string

-> char *str = "abc;20;xyz";
where a integer variable b=20

Now whenever I update the variable 'b', lets say now b=40 and read the string, it should read as

"abc;40;xyz"

Can anyone help me with an appropriate command or a user defined function to achieve this in C.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: You've heard of [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: Will the number always be two digits or less?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate the value of 'b' from the string you could do this :

```
char input[] = "abc;40;xyz";
int b = -1;

sscanf(input,"%*[^';'];%d%*s", &b);

printf("b = %d\n", b); // b = 40
```

If you want to build the string with the value of 'b' you could do this :

```
char *output = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
int b = 40;

snprintf(output,20,"abc;%d;xyz",b);
printf("output = %s\n",output); // output = abc;40;xyz
```